# Why is my pytorch code raising RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: pytorch

When I run a standard training loop on what appears to be a well designed model, I get this error.

`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation`

I found documentation mentioning that most PyTorch operations that update inplace have an underscore postfix, like tensor.add_. (This is like tf.Variable.assign_add). But I don't call any such method.

I get the error on a model like this. I expected the training loop to raise no errors.

```
class model(nn.Module):

def forward(self, image):
  image_mean = torch.mean(image, dim=(-3, -2, -1))
  image -= image_mean

and then I use a standard training loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

`image -= image_mean`

is not the same as

`image = image - image_mean`

The former updates the value of a tensor. The latter creates new tensors in PyTorch.

I learned about assignment operators in C, where a += b does indeed mean a = a + b. But that's not true in Python, or, apparently C++.